# Android: Facebook Applink cURL to java

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have been trying to get the cURL command translated into java code so that I can create a new AppLink object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api

I downloaded cURL and then typed in the following in Windows which worked and returned a applink ID:

> curl -k -g https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts -F
>   access_token="INSERTED MY OWN APP_TOKEN" -F name="Android App Link
>   Object Example" -F
>   android='[{"url":"sharesample://story/1234","package":"com.facebook.samples.sharesample","app_name":"ShareSample",},]'
>   -F web='{"should_fallback" : false,}'

Would anyone know how to convert the curl code into Java so that I can use it on my server?

Also I would like to find out if there is a way to found to query for all the applinks that are created for a particularly package name so that I can see everything that was created?

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever http client library you're using, search its documentation or for examples that show how to make `multipart/form-data` requests. The cURL command you are showing is making a multipart request, each `-F` being a body part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent hours researching this and finally found this piece of code from 1997 that I thought might no longer work as methods get deprecated and modified it for facebook applinks: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077532/learn-java/java-tip-34--posting-via-java.html

Then I used Spring to generate this endpoint and now its working and returns an app link id:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/applink", method=RequestMethod.GET)
      public void applink() {

            URL url;
            URLConnection urlConn;
            DataOutputStream printout;
            DataInputStream input;

            try {
                url = new URL ("https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts");
                // URL connection channel.
                urlConn = url.openConnection();
                // Let the run-time system (RTS) know that we want input.
                urlConn.setDoInput (true);
                // Let the RTS know that we want to do output.
                urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
                // No caching, we want the real thing.
                urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
                // Specify the content type.
                urlConn.setRequestProperty
                ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                // Send POST output.
                printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream ());
                String content =
                        "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode("INSERT APP ACCESS TOKEN", "UTF-8") +
                        "&name=" + URLEncoder.encode("Android App Link Object Example", "UTF-8") +
                        "&android=" + URLEncoder.encode("[{'url':'sharesample://story/1234', 'package':'com.facebook.samples.sharesample','app_name':'ShareSample'}]", "UTF-8") +
                        "&web=" + URLEncoder.encode("{'should_fallback' : false}", "UTF-8");
                        printout.writeBytes(content);
                        printout.flush ();
                        printout.close ();
                        // Get response data.
                        input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream ());

                        BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
                        String str;
                        while (null != ((str = d.readLine())))
                        {
                        System.out.println (str);
                        //textArea.appendText (str + "\n");
                        }
                        input.close ();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      }
```